# Pushing elements to vector where elements should have a specific lifetime

Tags: rust, vector, lifetime

I am trying to append a formatted string as bytes to the headers field. But I keep getting compilations errors regarding lifetimes.

```
pub struct Response<'a> {
    status_line: &'a [u8],
    headers: Vec<&'a [u8]>,
    contents: &'a [u8],
}

impl<'a> Response<'a> {
    fn new() -> Response<'a> {
        Response {
            status_line: OK_STATUS,
            headers: vec![b"\0", b"\0"],
            contents: &[b'\0'],
        }
    }

    fn build(&mut self) {
        let mut v: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();

        v.extend(self.status_line);

        let b: &'a [u8] = format!("Content-Length: {}\r\n", self.contents.len()).as_bytes();

        self.headers.push(b);

        for h in self.headers.iter() {
            v.extend(*h);
        }

        v.extend(self.contents);
    }
}
```

The error I keep getting reads:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:23:27
   |
9  | impl<'a> Response<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
23 |         let b: &'a [u8] = format!("Content-Length: {}\r\n", self.contents.len()).as_bytes();
   |                --------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                |          |
   |                |          creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
   |                type annotation requires that borrow lasts for `'a`
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `format` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0716`.
```

I need help adding the byte arrays to the headers. The problem seems to be that life spans are not matching up.

I have tried this:

```
let n = self.contents.len();
let s = format!("Content-Length: {}\r\n", n);
let b = s.as_bytes();
```

where it shows that "s" does not live long enough. I tried something dumber to see what would happen which was:

```
let n = self.contents.len();
let s: &'a String = &format!("Content-Length: {}\r\n", n);
let b = s.as_bytes();
```

The error I get from this states that the type annotation requires that borrow lasts for ''a', but am not sure how to address that.

**Work Around** as per @nwlon and @"John Kugelman". I changed the field types as to make the response own the data and avoid lifetime issues

```
pub struct Response<'a> {
    status_line: &'a [u8],
    headers: Vec<u8>,
    contents: Vec<u8>,
}

impl<'a> Response<'a> {
    fn new() -> Response<'a> {
        Response {
            status_line: OK_STATUS,
            headers: Vec::<u8>::new(),
            contents: Vec::<u8>::new(),
        }
    }

    fn build(&mut self) {
        let mut output: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();

        output.extend(self.status_line);

        self.headers
            .extend(format!("Content-Length: {}\r\n", self.contents.len()).as_bytes());

        output.extend(&self.headers);
        output.extend(&self.contents);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it an option to just use a `Vec<Vec<u8>>` for headers? From the code sample, you're formatting the strings, which requires materializing them as `String` anyway. Using `Vec<'a [u8]>` would require that each element of the vector outlives the struct, which isn't possible from within the `build` function.

Comment: @mwln thanks for the input. I was working under the impression that [u8] would be better for performance, thats why I wanted to go that route. But yes it can be Vec<Vec<u8>>, i will explore that option. I have a hard time understanding why each element can't out live the struct, isn't that the purpuse of specifying lifetimes?

Comment: Each element *can* outlive the struct, but that's difficult to accomplish. When you call `format!` and create an owned `String`, how are you going to keep the `String` alive? Somebody's got to take ownership of it, somebody who will outlive the `Response` struct. The `build()` method can't own it because its local variables will get dropped when it returns. `self` only holds references, so it's not going to own it. So... you've got to return it to the caller? But returning it will move it and invalidate the references... Ack! It's much more natural if `Response` owns its own data.